# how to use non-standard evaluation in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to use the variable name in a for loop but failed. I thought the problem is on the Non-Standard Evaluation in R.

I tried the method on this website: [Standard evaluation and non-standard evaluation in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49044806/standard-evaluation-and-non-standard-evaluation-in-r).

```
library(pROC)
library(tidyverse)
roc1 <- aSAH %>% roc(outcome, s100b)

plot(roc1)

a = 'roc1'

# method from Stack overflow
plot(!!rlang::sym(a))

# Some other attempts
plot(sym(a))

plot(!sym(a))

plot(!!sym(a))
```

Any help will be highly appreciated!!

Comment: just `plot(get(a))` would work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The return of `sym` should be evaluated with `eval` or `rlang::eval_tidy` before they can be used in `plot`. For example:

```
a <- 1:10

x <- sym('a')

plot(eval(x))
plot(rlang::eval_tidy(x))
```

[`!!` or `!!!`](https://rlang.r-lib.org/reference/quasiquotation.html) are forcing operators used to force evaluation in tidyverse functions.

Comment: Sorry to bother you, I have a new problem, I would appreciate it if you have time to help me look at it. (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68141082/matching-controls-to-cases-using-multiple-conditions-in-r)

Answer (score 3):

#### TLDR

Be careful with NSE, it is usually a design choice in favor of interactive use as opposed of programmatic use.

As others have pointed out, `plot` uses standard evaluation, and thus `!!` will not work directly (`!!` only works in quoting functions).

Other users have already given answers to your post, so I think I will focus on when to use NSE in code - because I don't think you've expressed well enough how you plan to use it or why.

#### But first some general info

Non standard evaluation is generally used to capture the end user's input in some way. A good portion of the `tidyverse` have functions that use NSE, specifically `dplyr`. These functions will 'quote' the users input, capturing an expression to be evaluated in another context. With `dplyr`, our first argument is always a `data.frame` and the rest of the arguments are *usually* quoted and are evaluated in the context of the `data.frame` (more specifically a [data mask](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/dplyr_data_masking.html)) before searching the rest of the environment.

Just a tangent before continuing, NSE didn't start with the `tidyverse`, because there are base R functions that use NSE. For example, `subset()` or anytime you use a `formula`.

#### Why use NSE

Typically, I find there are only two reason why I would code up a NSE function. I either want to extend a function that already uses NSE or I'm helping the end user with the DRY (do not repeat yourself) paradigm.

`dplyr` is a great package for interactive use, but the second you want to make a custom function that uses NSE (to mirror the `dplyr` style), you have to start working with quosures, which can be a huge pain at first.

Here is an example of a function that would use NSE.

I often find myself needing to insure that a certain keys only exists once in the data. The `duplicated` function helps determine which keys are problems, but I also want to return the rows that match those keys.

Consider the following reprex

```r
library(dplyr)
#> Warning: package 'dplyr' was built under R version 3.6.3
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
df <- tibble(
  lower_case = sample(letters, 30, T),
  upper_case = sample(LETTERS, 30, T)
)

df
#> # A tibble: 30 x 2
#>    lower_case upper_case
#>    <chr>      <chr>     
#>  1 d          G         
#>  2 x          P         
#>  3 x          A         
#>  4 s          E         
#>  5 s          R         
#>  6 h          W         
#>  7 w          X         
#>  8 m          E         
#>  9 b          V         
#> 10 j          H         
#> # ... with 20 more rows
```

If I wanted to view all rows that match a duplicated value of the column `lower_case` I would write in `dplyr`:

```r
attempt1 <- df %>% 
  filter(lower_case %in% subset(lower_case, duplicated(lower_case)))
```

But I find that kinda cumbersome, so could will write a function that will modify my argument to the correct call for me:

```r
all_duplicates <- function(.data, .expr, verbose = F){
  #cature the expression as quosure
  .expr <- enquo(.expr)
  
  #the repetitive expression
  new_quo <- quo(!!.expr %in% subset(!!.expr,duplicated(!!.expr)))
  
  if(verbose) print(new_quo)
  
  filter(.data, !!new_quo) #since filter is a quoting function
                           #I can use !! here
  
}
```

Now I need to write very little to do that specific task

```r
attempt2 <- df %>%
  all_duplicates(lower_case)

identical(attempt1, attempt2)
#> [1] TRUE
```

I included a debugging `verbose` argument as a sanity check to make sure the new quo expression was formulated correctly.

```r
all_duplicates(df, lower_case, verbose = T)
#> <quosure>
#> expr: ^(^lower_case) %in% subset(^lower_case, duplicated(^lower_case))
#> env:  0000000015FB9768
#> # A tibble: 17 x 2
#>    lower_case upper_case
#>    <chr>      <chr>     
#>  1 x          P         
#>  2 x          A         
#>  3 s          E         
#>  4 s          R         
#>  5 h          W         
#>  6 b          V         
#>  7 n          W         
#>  8 b          O         
#>  9 l          D         
#> 10 e          G         
#> 11 n          H         
#> 12 r          H         
#> 13 n          T         
#> 14 h          S         
#> 15 l          G         
#> 16 e          A         
#> 17 r          B
all_duplicates(df, upper_case, verbose = T)
#> <quosure>
#> expr: ^(^upper_case) %in% subset(^upper_case, duplicated(^upper_case))
#> env:  000000001A6B5E60
#> # A tibble: 19 x 2
#>    lower_case upper_case
#>    <chr>      <chr>     
#>  1 d          G         
#>  2 x          P         
#>  3 x          A         
#>  4 s          E         
#>  5 h          W         
#>  6 m          E         
#>  7 j          H         
#>  8 n          W         
#>  9 b          O         
#> 10 u          J         
#> 11 e          G         
#> 12 n          H         
#> 13 r          H         
#> 14 p          O         
#> 15 c          P         
#> 16 z          G         
#> 17 l          G         
#> 18 a          J         
#> 19 e          A
```

Here's the kicker, lets say I have a list of `data.frame`s and I want to apply this function on all of them, *HOWEVER* the column of interest for each `data.frame` is different.

To do this you would need to convert the string into a symbol with `sym()`, as you were doing.

This is the biggest downfall of NSE in that you need to have extra care if you plan to use them programmatically. Mores specifically, the END USER needs to remember how to use the function programmatically - which is not as intuitive as a standard evaluation function.

I'd be remised to mention that `dplyr` has made a lot of development in order to tackle this problem, but that doesn't mean these will be open for use in your functions (see [`across`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/across.html))

Here is a standard evaluation variant of the same thing, except it just expects any vector.

```r
all_duplicates2 <- function(x) x %in% x[duplicated(x)]
#can still use it with dplyr
attempt3 <- df %>% filter(all_duplicates2(lower_case))
```

the programmatic example

```r
df2 <- tibble(
    lower_case = sample(letters, 30, T),
    upper_case = sample(LETTERS, 30, T)
  )

l <- list(df, df2)
#applying function on two data frames, but different columns
standard_l <- purrr::map2(
   l, c("upper_case","lower_case"), 
   ~.x[all_duplicates2(.x[[.y]]),])
non_standard_l <- purrr::map2(
   l, c("upper_case","lower_case"),
   ~all_duplicates(.x, !!sym(.y))) #doable with NSE, but not many
                                   # people know this trick

identical(standard_l, non_standard_l)
#> [1] TRUE
```

<sup>Created on 2021-05-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>